# Creating a hash from an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I've got data in an array like

```
$a[0] = (a1,b1,c1);
$a[1] = (a2,b2,c2);   # and so on
```

I want to create a hash where the first element is the key and the 2nd and 3rd element are the values

So a1=>b1 and a2=>b2

Any help is appreciated

```
if (open(MYFILE, "Task1.txt")) {
    @airportdata = <MYFILE>; 
    close(MYFILE); 
} else { 
    print "The File Does Not Exist!\n"; 
    exit 1;
}
```

Comment: `my %hash;`
`@hash{@{$a[0]}} = @{$a[1]};`

Comment: How to insert 2 elements as the value of the key?

Comment: You specs suggest one thing (values with multiple elements), but your desired output suggests another (a one-element value).  What is your desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following, which will give you a hash filled with array refs. I assumed the first value is the key.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my %airportdata;
open(my $fh, '<', "Task1.txt") or die $!;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp $line;
  my @fields = split /,/, $line;
  $airportdata{$fields[0]} = [ @fields[1,2] ];
} 
close($fh); 

__END__
%airportdata = (
  'a1' => ['b1', 'c1'],
  'a2' => ['b2', 'c'],
);
```

You should always `use strict` and `use warnings`. Checking if the `open` worked was well done, but I changed it to make the code more readable. Also, always use three-argument `open`.

Furthermore, I'm using an array slice to access both fields 1 and 2 at the same time, returning a list.

Comment: Thanks that did get the job done. Although [ @fields[1,2] ] didnt give me a value but rather a weird Array[0x0000b] result when I try to get the value of the key

Comment: I believe you meant `close($fh);`.

Comment: @Kenosis thank you. - It is an array reference. Those are Perl's way to create multilevel data structures. You should read up on them in [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @likeafile=(q(a1, b1, c1),
               q(a2, b2, c2),
               q(a3, b3, c3),
               q(antelope, brisket, cloud));
my %hash=();
for my $l (@likeafile) {
    my @a=split(/\s*,\s*/,$l);
    $hash{$a[0]} = [@a[1..2]];
}

#simple access example
my $key="a3";

my $first=$hash{$key}[0];
my $second=$hash{$key}[1];

print "FAIL $first $second \n" unless ($first eq 'b3' and $second eq 'c3');

#find all 3rd elements that are longer than 3 characters
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    my $second=$hash{$key}[1];
    print "$second\n" if (length($second) > 3);
}
```